# Semantic UI: get current dropdown search input text

Tags: search, input, text, dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm trying to filter some results I will get from an api using Semantic UI's dropdown search component.

---

The issue is that I don't know how to get the text I'm typing in the input field

---

The dropdown search I have:

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" id="user-dropdown">
    <input id="user-dropdown-input" name="country" type="hidden">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Search...</div>
    <div class="menu" id="user-dropdown-menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="af">
            <span class="description">123</span>
            <span class="text">User123</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="af">
            <span class="description">123</span>
            <span class="text">User123</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="af">
            <span class="description">123</span>
            <span class="text">User123</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

How dropdown is initialized:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
        clearable: true,
        fullTextSearch: true
    });
});
```

---

What I tried:

```
$('#user-dropdown').on('keyup', function () {
    let input = $('#user-dropdown');

    console.log('Val: ' + input.dropdown().val());
    // also tried: $('#user-dropdown-input').val()
    //             $('#user-dropdown-input').html()
    //             $('#user-dropdown-input').text()
});
```

---

Basically what I want is `if I type "abc"` to `print the value "abc"` into the console, but `I don't know how to get that value`.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was searching the input used for search that looks like:

```
<input class="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
```

and I added a type to this input

```
document.getElementsByClassName('search').type = 'text';
```

and then got the value by class on keyup

```
   $('.search').keyup(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```